# Getting wrong 12 hrs format date from 24 hrs format - Android

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I have `24 hours` time format and need to convert `12 hrous` format. I used below code, but it shows wrong format. can anyone suggest me

> ### 24 hrs:
>
> 08:00
>
> 12:00
>
> 13:00
>
> 13:15
>
> 15:35
>
> 20:24

after converting output shows following

> 12hrs:
>   ----- 08:00 AM
>
> 12:00 PM
>
> 01:00 PM
>
> 01:15 AM
>
> 03:35 AM
>
> 08:24 AM

I Used following code:

```
public String addTime(int hour, int minute, int minutesToAdd, boolean isAdd) {
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 6, 18, hour, minute);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minutesToAdd);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
    return date;
}
```

Comment: How are you getting your time? As string?

Comment: Everything is fine but at the time adding 15mins to current time it shows wrong

Comment: Is the 24 hour format date in String form?

Comment: I mean in this got AM instead of PM after 1 PM

Comment: I actually assined individual Integer hour and minute to calendar for 15mins increment to current time. then getting time from calender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two date formats: one to parse, and one to format.So your code would be something like

```
       String _24HourTime = hour +":"+ minute";
       SimpleDateFormat _24HourSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
       SimpleDateFormat _12HourSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
       Date _24HourDt = _24HourSDF.parse(_24HourTime);
       System.out.println(_12HourSDF.format(_24HourDt));
```